# final class and final member functions

Tags: c++11

Say I have the base class:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo();
};
```

and the derived class is final `struct A final : public Base`. Does it make sense to make the member functions `final` as well? I've seen in several places e.g.

```
struct A final : public Base {
    void foo() final;
}
```

I am not sure it provides any value in this case as if the class itself is `final` I guess all the member functions are `final` by default as well. Am I missing something? Are there any guidelines?

Comment: As your struct/class is final, derived members can not exist, I'd say declaring functions as final is just personal preference in this case. [See also](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Answer (score 2):

In case a struct or a class (`A` in your case) is `final`, you cannot declare another one inheriting it. Therefore, there's no need to also declare any methods as `final`.

Maybe this is a convention in some places to be clear that this method also cannot be overridden (just as a "reminder" for the `final` of the struct).